# Is there a sequence of unbounded closed intervals such that its intersection is empty?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Is there a sequence of unbounded closed intervals $J_1\supseteq J_2 \supseteq J_3 \supseteq \cdots$ such that $\bigcap _{n=1} ^{\infty} J_n = \emptyset$. By an unbounded closed interval I mean an interval of the form $[a,\infty) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ge a\}$.

My answer to the question is yes taking the sequence $[1,\infty),[2,\infty),[3,  \infty), ...$ because suppose $b \in  \bigcap _{n=1} ^{\infty} J_n$. Then there exists an interval in the sequence such the $b\lt a_i$ whereby $b \notin [a_i, \infty) $ hence $b $ cannot be in $\bigcap _{n=1} ^{\infty} J_n$. Therefore the intersection is empty.

*Is my answer correct and if so is my reasoning correct? If not can you please provide the correct justification for the correct answer. Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is correct but your proof isn't phrased quite right: if $b \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n$, then $b \in [n, \infty)$ for every natural number $n$, which is impossible, because if $b$ is any real number there is a natural number $n$ such that $b < n$, so that $b \not\in [n, \infty)$. (The way you have phrased it, it's not very clear what $a_i$ is.)

Comment: I think this is what the OP is getting at when they say "Then there exists an interval in the sequence such the $b<a_i$" - that every real is below some natural. Of course, this could be written more clearly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: sure. I've watered down my critique to be about the OP's phrasing.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, that's right (although see my comment in response to Rob Arthan's answer - it could be written more clearly). In particular, note that even though the notation "$[1,\infty)$" (for example) may suggest that the set is not closed, it is in fact closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is essentially a "proof by contradiction".  You start by assuming the negation of what you want to prove ("$b\in \cap_{n=1}^\infty J_n$") and arrive at a contradiction ("b is not in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty J_n$").

A "direct proof" would be "If $p\in R$ then, by the Archimedian property, there exist an integer, n, n> p.  Then p is not $J_n$ so p in not in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty J_n$".